# Yii2 Behavior method in model

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I create a behavior in **`common\models\ReservationBehavior`** and there is a method

```
 public function getLastflight(){
  return 'last Flight';
 }
```

Use this behavior in common\models\User

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
       'ReservationModelBehavior' => ReservationModelBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

now i want to get value from lastFlight in

```
public function fields(){
 return 'lastFlight'
 }
```

How can I get value from behavior method?

Comment: is your `fields()` function defined inside your `User` model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**`DOCS`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html)

> Because this class is a behavior when it is attached to a component,
>   that component will then also have the properties and methods defined
>   in the behavior.

So if your function `fields()` is inside your `User` model then you can call the function via `$this`

```
public function fields(){
    return $this->getLastflight();
}
```